# 4th finger free hand

Tags: piano, technique

Helow! I have been playing piano almost 3 years, first 2 years were great, i had made so big progress  that then i started revolutionary etude,  played it fast  and after a while i noticed that my left hand was more free,weightless than my right hand, now i can hardly do a trel with 2 3 finger, but the one that most annoys me is that when i use my 4th finger for example in WAMs sonata in c my whole hand gets tired and burdened, i compared 100 times my right and left hand  and i feel something moving in my right hand that  makes my hand tired, please help me, i tried lot excercises every day i play 10 hanons , arpegios and  other exercises very slowly, but with no result i feel really lost and depressed, what should i do? Does anyone have the same experience?

Comment: You say you "feel something moving in my right hand"--what? A bone? A stray muscle? A tendon or ligament? Something else? If that something is a bone that you don't feel in your left hand, that's a sign of trouble--and I dare say that you likely want to see a doctor about that bone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A thousand hours of Hanon is of no value if you do it wrong.

Trills and tremolos come from your pronator and supinator muscles, not the fingers.  And, there are no muscles in your fingers so your focus is in the wrong place. Your teacher should know this.

If your fourth finger is weak, you need to make a simple adjustment to your forearm which will align that bone and corresponding tendons. Your teacher should know this.

The arm shouldn't necessarily be "weightless" but rather, you control the weight.  Likewise, there is no such thing as playing relaxed, just don't use the wrong muscles to play.  Tension comes from using the wrong muscles not designed to play the piano. Consequently pianists relax the wrong muscles, the ones that they are supposed to be using.   If you are playing with gravity, your hand shouldn't feel tired unless you are using two muscles simultaneously.  Your teacher should know this. Each bundle of muscle fibers becomes a tendon which attaches to various places on your finger bones.  Flex a forearm muscle, it pulls a tendon which pulls your finger bone.  One muscle moves one bone in one direction.  Then there are opposite muscles to move the bone back (flexors/extensors, bicep/triceps, etcetera).  When a pianist does something like, abduct the fingers and flex at the same time, that results in two muscles pulling one bone in two directions (tug of war within the hand).  This gives us fatigue, cramps, uneven playing, etcetera.  Most teachers don't know anatomy, physics nor the mechanics of the arm so they prescribe "Practice more" when in reality the student just needs to practice correctly.  Like that old wives tale, if you wake up with a hangover, drink more alcohol. More wrong never makes right. The whole hand and all five fingers can only move in one direction at a time and most of us have made or make these errors in movement. They create vector forces which pull the hand in two directions simultaneously.  So, if you are trying to play a downward scale, while one of your other fingers may be pulling up and in the opposite direction, the hand will fatigue and you won't be able to relax the muscles.  What's a hand to do? Your teacher should know this.

You may also need to work out groupings.  Again, use the pronator and supinator to play groups of notes rather than each individual finger.  Combine the pronator with gravity with grouping and use your abductors and flexors minimally and you'll improve.

You may need a new teacher. Just because someone can play doesn't mean they can teach or even know what they are doing.  I studied with a concert pianist whose suggestion was "Practice more."  I remember struggling with an arpeggio on some piece and never mastered it.  When I procured a new teacher, she said "You need to tilt here and forward shift your thumb" and poof, the lick was instantly there.  No practice required.  It is mechanics not magic nor rote. Driving a car with an alignment issue will not resolve itself with more driving.  Why do we think our hands are different? Playing the piano is ALL about physics.  Sometimes I think my car mechanic would make a better teacher.  He knows all about torque and force vectors. Most piano teachers don't.

The thing you feel moving is probably a misaligned tendon gliding over a bone or something.  It is trying to work in a straight line but something is pulling it out of its alignment.  Make sure you don't have ulnar nor radial deviation when you play.  Again, the flexors are not designed for playing the piano.  The flexors move your fingers which have no muscles.  Use gravity, the elbow, the shoulder, grouping, in/out, up/down and your playing will be truly effortless.  Flexor (finger) players will always run into these problems. They will strain their tendons causing them to inflame then they will press on the median nerve:  Median Nerve Entrapment (aka carpal tunnel syndrome). The solution of course is to stop moving improperly and the inflammation will go away.  Or you can take drugs, wear splints or have surgery. Run fast and far from any doctor who treats a symptom and not the problem. The symptom is numbness and pain, the problem is moving improperly.  If you have a nail in your shoe impaling your foot, would you take anti inflammatory drugs or remove the nail?

When you walk up 10 flights of stairs, it is your big quad muscles that get tired because they are doing all the work, not your feet.  Your feet are moving where your big muscles place them.  When playing the piano, let your big muscles do all the work, not the little ones.  The arm places the finger, the finger doesn't drag the arm.  When walking down stairs, it is effortless because it is gravity which pulls us down.  When playing the piano, let gravity play the keys.  Never press into a key. Once you hit the keybed, it will be a battle of force between your tiny ligaments and the piano.  Trust me, the piano will win.

Answer (score 0):

"come from your pronator and supinator muscles"- what do i use while playing?fingers? Than how to play with using pronator and supinator?and how to "make a simple adjustment to my forearm"?i dont know wich are wrong and correct muscles.why do i have the problem with my right hand and not with left one?(my teacher says because of revolutionary etude in wich the mainc theme and pressure falls on right hand)and do you know ointment or something that would.relax correct muscles?

Comment: When you cut an apple using a knife, you use the knife while cutting the apple, but the knife itself is not doing the work required to cut open the apple; you are. Similarly, when you press down a key with your finger, while it is your finger that is in contact with the key, the one that's doing the work is your muscles. Without the knife you won't be able to cut the apple; without the muscles, there's no way anyone could have pressed the key down with their fingers alone.